# Support IntelliSense for pytest fixtures in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I can't find how to connect IntelliSense for fixtures in pytest. This functionality has long been in PyCharm.
https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/08/pycharm-2018-2-and-pytest-fixtures/
There are even addition, that do not work for a long time - cameron.vscode-pytest.
Maybe I miss something?

Comment: I was about  to ask if there is a way to have Python take the fixture return and turn it into an instance of the fixture's internal class so the editor can see it as such and thus provide code completions.  So far no luck.

Answer (score 2):

VS code added this functionality with the 2023 February release (1.76). https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_76#_improved-intellisense-support-for-pytest